# English Stress and Rule Based Accounts SPE Chomsky/Halle

Tags: phonology, chomsky

Is the following morpho-syntactic representation of the below phrase using brackets correct?

**Long Bike Ride**

And subsequently, would the below cyclically applied rules showing the resulting stress levels represented by numbers also be correct for "long bike ride" where the meaning is for the duration of the ride rather than the physicality of the bike?

[[Long]A [[Bike]N [Ride]N]N ]NP
____1___   **_1**   ___1_____      Main Stress Rule

[Long [Bike Ride]NP
_____      **1**     **_2**        Compound Stress Rule

[Long Bike Ride]NP
____1___   **_2**   ___3_____      Compound Stress Rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bracketing is correct. The Compound stress rule will apply to give the 1-2 contour to "bike-ride"; then the Nuclear stress rule assigns 1 stress to "bike", causing across the board reductions of other stressed, so you get a surface 2-1-3 profile. This is analogous to SPE's derivation 16a, for "black board-eraser".